# Python Multiprocessing Pool (Concurent Futures ProcessPoolExecutor) slow down with increasing number of workers

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

### Problem description

Hi, I've got a computationally heavy function which I am running in parallel.

I've noticed that when using the concurrent futures `ProcessPoolExecutor` (or the multiprocessing `Pool`) the processes slows down when using more workers (or adding more tasks). I.e. when I run my code on 2 workers, the average execution time of a process is around 0.7s, however when using 16 workers (the `cpu_count` of my processor) the average execution time of the same process is of 6.7s.

A similar thing happens when running the same calculation on more tasks.
See the test code and results below.

### Test code

```py
import concurrent.futures
import os
from time import perf_counter

import numpy as np


def func(foo):
    start_time = perf_counter()
    long_calculation = np.random.random(size=100000000).std()
    stop_time = perf_counter()
    execution_time = stop_time - start_time
    return execution_time


cpu_count = os.cpu_count()
assert cpu_count is not None
print(f"CPU Count: {cpu_count}")


# ======= Increasing Tasks ============
# max_workers = 10
# for tasks in [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 1000]:

# ======= Increasing Max Workers ============
tasks = 50
for max_workers in range(1, cpu_count + 1):
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers) as pool:
        total_exec_time: float = 0.0
        processes = pool.map(func, range(tasks))
        for process_result in processes:
            total_exec_time += process_result
        print(
            f"{tasks} tasks on {max_workers} workers - average process execution time:  {round(total_exec_time / tasks, 2)}s"
        )
```

### The results

#### Increasing the number of `max_workers`

```
PU Count: 16
50 tasks on 1 workers - average process execution time:  0.65s
50 tasks on 2 workers - average process execution time:  0.76s
50 tasks on 3 workers - average process execution time:  0.97s
50 tasks on 4 workers - average process execution time:  1.16s
50 tasks on 5 workers - average process execution time:  1.6s
50 tasks on 6 workers - average process execution time:  1.9s
50 tasks on 7 workers - average process execution time:  2.29s
50 tasks on 8 workers - average process execution time:  2.67s
50 tasks on 9 workers - average process execution time:  3.02s
50 tasks on 10 workers - average process execution time:  3.5s
50 tasks on 11 workers - average process execution time:  4.0s
50 tasks on 12 workers - average process execution time:  4.73s
50 tasks on 13 workers - average process execution time:  5.37s
50 tasks on 14 workers - average process execution time:  5.66s
50 tasks on 15 workers - average process execution time:  6.07s
50 tasks on 16 workers - average process execution time:  6.71s
```

#### Increasing the number of tasks

```
10 workers with 1 tasks - average process execution time:  0.67s
10 workers with 2 tasks - average process execution time:  0.84s
10 workers with 5 tasks - average process execution time:  1.91s
10 workers with 10 tasks - average process execution time:  3.82s
10 workers with 20 tasks - average process execution time:  3.52s
10 workers with 50 tasks - average process execution time:  3.88s
10 workers with 100 tasks - average process execution time:  4.0s
10 workers with 1000 tasks - average process execution time:  3.92s
```

### Results

Overall, the whole program runs faster, however it is slowing down progressively. I would like it to keep the same efficiency, no matter how many workers I use.

> NOTE
>
> The CPU usage is increasing linearly alongside the `max_workers` parameter.
> The CPU usage is at 100% when using 15 or 16 `max_workers` (the idle CPU usage is around 7%) and my RAM has always plenty of free space.

### Using multiprocessing

Side note: I get the exact same results using the multiprocessing `Pool`.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

...
    with Pool(processes=max_workers) as pool:
        ...
```

Comment: `for workers in range` - you're passing the entire workload to each process, so massively duplicating the work rather than divvying it up

Comment: You can't map like this inside a `for` loop. `map` _is_ the functional programming approach to `for` and you're doubling it up by using both

Comment: @roganjosh Your comments don't make sense here. The outer loop controls the number of worker threads. Each iteration is a separate benchmark.

Comment: @MichaelButscher it spawns a pool for each number of worker processes? Seriously?

Comment: Have you read the code? Spawning a pool of workers inside a `for` loop?

Comment: @roganjosh It has to spawn a new pool because the number of workers can only be set on pool creation.

Comment: Your issue is more than likely due to memory consumption rather than CPU. Each execution of *np.random.random(size=100000000).std()* uses quite a lot of memory. Let's call that M. This means that you will have, at any given point in time, max_workers * M RAM in use. You also need to take care of how you use max_workers. Don't use cpu_count (the default if not specified) on Xeon type processors. For example, my machine has a 10-core Xeon. os.cpu_count() reports 20 whereas I would never want to use more than 9 workers

Comment: And that same pool is spawned N times to do exactly the same work over again. It's right there in the timings

Comment: If I was wrong, how do you explain the time increase with every new process added?

Comment: It is not the same pool. All pools have different numbers of worker thread. The code is made to test the timing depending on number of worker threads.

Comment: @roganjosh Currently I don't have an explanation but the code does not do what you describe.

Comment: The point of the pool and the map is to divide the work across processes. You don't start a new pool for every one of your processor counts. You've just made it O(N^2)

Comment: It's right there. It repeats the entire calculation from scratch based on `cpu_count + 1`

Comment: @roganjosh The code as a whole is of course not performant because it is testing performance for different worker counts in the pool.

Comment: It's duplicating the work. None of it is chucked, it just re-does the same thing over and over when you increase the processor count

Comment: The ProcessPool is in a for loop as a benchmark for testing different amount of workers.
As to the RAM usage, the peak usage on multiple runs I've observed was 28Gb out of 32Gb (running on 16 workers), so I don't think this is the cause of the increasing time, espacially on lower amount of workers.

Comment: @roganjosh As usual for some types of experiments the same thing is repeated under slightly different conditions.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have no idea what you're talking about. The timings back up my analysis. You're telling me I'm wrong, but have no explanation for what the issue is, and the timings back my analysis

Comment: @roganjosh As stated above, the for loop is to run `n` ***different*** benchmarks, each with a different pool size. The loop is deliberately repeating the same workload to see how the elapsed time (per task) varies with pool size. First iteration it runs 50 tasks with a pool of 1, then it runs the same 50 tasks with a pool of 2, and so on, so that the difference between iterations is pool size, thus allowing the effect of pool size to be observed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By modifying the code to do purely CPU-intensive work rather than a combination of CPU/RAM stress, we can show (with little doubt) that the issue is due to memory consumption.

```
from time import perf_counter
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from random import random

SIZE = 5_000_000

def func(_):
    start_time = perf_counter()
    for _ in range(SIZE):
        random()
    return perf_counter() - start_time

def main():
    tasks = 50
    for max_workers in range(2, 10):
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers) as pool:
            total_exec_time = sum(pool.map(func, range(tasks)))
            print(f"{tasks} tasks on {max_workers} workers - average process execution time:  {round(total_exec_time / tasks, 2)}s")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
50 tasks on 2 workers - average process execution time:  0.22s
50 tasks on 3 workers - average process execution time:  0.22s
50 tasks on 4 workers - average process execution time:  0.23s
50 tasks on 5 workers - average process execution time:  0.23s
50 tasks on 6 workers - average process execution time:  0.23s
50 tasks on 7 workers - average process execution time:  0.24s
50 tasks on 8 workers - average process execution time:  0.24s
50 tasks on 9 workers - average process execution time:  0.24s
```

**Notes:**

```
Python 3.11.2
macOS 13.2.1 (Ventura)
CPU 3GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W
RAM 32GB
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the answer, when I ran your code it still behaved the same way. After increasing SIZE to 50_000_000_000 it becomes more apparent, on my computer (16 cores) running this code on 2 workers takes 1.5s, however on 16 workers 3.5s (the execution times are gradually increasing just like in the original question).

Comment: @janboro Then it's a platform issue. I assume you're running Windows

Answer (score 1):

> Overall, the whole program runs faster, however it is slowing down progressively. I would like it to keep the same efficiency, no matter how many workers I use.

in short you can't always do that, each process is assigned a core with only around 5 MB of cache, if your process tries to use more memory than that it has to use the RAM, which has a limited bandwidth and is the reason of the bottleneck here, python alone takes much more than 5MB for its internal calls and will almost always be contending on the RAM bandwidth, there are also other bottlenecks like the OS scheduler and context switching.

lastly there is thermal throttling which happens when a CPU gets hotter, so you need a second CPU to spread the heat generation.

if you want the same speed when you increase the number of workers you have to increase the number of RAM chips and CPUs, which ultimately means, use cluster computing.

there are also faster methods like not storing the random numbers in memory and consuming them on construction which can eliminate this contention.

also using a language that runs on bare-metal like C++ will reduce the memory (and power) consumption which reduces this contention. (if you are not storing millions of numbers in memory).

Comment: Could you elaborate on consuming the variables on construction? It sounds like it might be an improvement I could do :)

Comment: @janboro it's like the code posted in the other answer, but maybe done better in a language with less memory consumption like C++, as python consumes a lot of memory for its internal calls.

Comment: @janboro i also think you are thermal throttling.

Comment: The code posted by @DarkKinght is a version using almost no memory at all, and it still behaves the same.
The ram usage is at 5GB out of 32GB. The CPU is usage is increasing proportionally to the number of workers (CPU threads|cores) used.

Comment: @janboro Not using much RAM ***space*** is very different from not using much RAM ***bandwidth***. Even simple operations in Python have relatively large overheads due to everything being an object, the interpreter parsing the bytecode, etc, etc. Dark Knight's code doesn't behave identically to yours, thus showing that reducing memory bandwidth contention Does have an impact. (Down from 10x elapsed time per task to 2x)

Comment: @janboro on your computer the reason why 16 workers take more than 2 workers is thermal throttling, the other answer does solve the RAM contention problem, to check that the issue is indeed thermal throttling you have to turn off turbo boosting in your BIOS, this is indeed 100 times slower than using numpy, which is why i recommended the low level language.

Answer (score 1):

After combining the [@DarkKnight answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843440/17163860) with [@Ahned AEK suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843413/17163860) and [@MatBailie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie) comment, I noticed it was indeed a problem of RAM bandwidth.

In order to test it, I added a sleep to wait between each calculation:

```py
...
from time import perf_counter, sleep

SIZE = 500_000

def func(_):
    total_time = 0.0
    for _ in range(SIZE):
        sleep(0.0001)
        start_time = perf_counter()
        random()
        total_time += perf_counter() - start_time
    return total_time
...
```

Doing so, allowed the code not to use the whole RAM bandwidth at once.

### Results

Running the above code showed that the execution times maintain consistent, no matter how many workers are used.

```
50 tasks on 1 workers - average process execution time:  0.72s
50 tasks on 2 workers - average process execution time:  0.75s
50 tasks on 3 workers - average process execution time:  0.73s
50 tasks on 4 workers - average process execution time:  0.72s
50 tasks on 5 workers - average process execution time:  0.70s
50 tasks on 6 workers - average process execution time:  0.66s
50 tasks on 7 workers - average process execution time:  0.66s
50 tasks on 8 workers - average process execution time:  0.65s
50 tasks on 9 workers - average process execution time:  0.65s
50 tasks on 10 workers - average process execution time:  0.64s
50 tasks on 11 workers - average process execution time:  0.64s
50 tasks on 12 workers - average process execution time:  0.65s
50 tasks on 13 workers - average process execution time:  0.65s
50 tasks on 14 workers - average process execution time:  0.65s
50 tasks on 15 workers - average process execution time:  0.66s
50 tasks on 16 workers - average process execution time:  0.67s
```

### Key Takeaway

The limiting factor was RAM **bandwidth**, which I have not considered.

It was **not** a problem of: full RAM, full CPU, thermal throttling.

```
Os: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Python: 3.10.6
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H
RAM: 32Gb 3200MHz DDR4 SODIMM CL22
```

Thanks to everyone taking the time answering my question and helping me find an answer!